# Importance of HTTP Methods in a REST Api

Tags: web-services, rest, jersey, jax-rs, restful-architecture

I am learning RESTful webservices using `JAX-RS` `Jersey`.
Although we have different HTTP Methods for different purposes like:

- `GET` for Reading a resource
- `DELETE` fro deleting a resource
- `PUT` and `POST` for Creating and Updating a resource.
- `PATCH` not sure what it is for.

Whats is the purpose of using all these method for specific purpose?

From My understanding every request goes to a method anotated with `@Path`. I could perform any operation I like in that method.

For Example:
I can perform all `CRUD` operations using only `GET` requests.

I want know the importance and scenarios where and how I can use these HTTP methods make my REST Api better.

Please point me to right question or link if this is been answered before.